# One Div Expand and other collapse using Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 3.2.0 and i have implemented Collapse function.
The issue is while i am clicking on first tab contents is getting expanded but while clicking on 2nd and 3rd tabs all tabs respective contents are getting expands at the same time.

The requirement is only one tabs content should open at the time while all other should be collapsed.

Comment: No one can help you if you don't show your code. Add a snippet to your question that contains only directly relevant code, and if you want, provide a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: this is jsfiddle path: http://jsfiddle.net/3owdesxg/2/